# What do I need to read/learn in order to enter a search term into google and fetch the results from console?

Tags: c#

Code padawan here teaching myself to code so pardon the ignorance.

I want to be able to enter a search term into console and return the search results from google to be displayed in google.

What do I need to learn/read in order to accomplish this?

**UPDATED**

1. Enter search term into console
2. Program takes this search term and
   runs it in google search
3. Take the results of this search query and
   output the first page to console

I hope this is clearer ^_^

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "search results from google to be displayed in google". Where exactly do you want to display the results?

Comment: @erenon - Since he is talking about C#, one can assume this is a .NET console project (using `System.Console`), not a unix shell.

Comment: Isn't that against google's T's & C's? Not that thousands of people aren't doing it currently of course...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class to retrieve results from google.

As for displaying them, I don't quite understand what you mean in your question.

You can always output them to the console.

Answer (score 0):

> return the search results from google
>   to be displayed in google.

Could you elaborate what you mean by display in google.

To send a query to google you will probably need an API key otherwise you will get a nastygram unless you change your user agent to something you aren't.

This project might be harder than it seems with all the extra hoops.